# Manipulating back task stack in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have three activities A,B,C,D.
When I use activity B, then previous activity is A. I will write it as A->B.
So when I click back I go to A.
However I want to start activity D from B. But instead of tree A->B->D I need to alter it to A->C->D. How can  do it in android?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it.

You can have a lok at the below links.

[First-](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) [Second-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369918/how-to-manage-activity-stack) and [this-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953799/android-activity-backstack-management)